# Giving format to a single column on WebGrid MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, styles, webgrid

I have an stored procedure from my DB and I transform it into a WebGrid in my Web application. The problem is that, since the columns I got from the stored procedure are dynamic (it means I don't how many columns are and each one's name) I don't specify the columns variable in grid.GetHtml() function, I have something like this:

```
@grid.GetHtml(fillEmptyRows: false,
        tableStyle: "table table-hover",
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
        firstText: "<< First",
        previousText: "< Back",
        nextText: "Next >",
        lastText: "Last >>"
        )
```

And that's it!

So, the question is, How can I give style to just one column?, for example I know that at least one column is "Name" and I want it to have "width:100px" Because if I just specify one column it will show just that column! Please I hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using Javascript -- I'm not sure if there's a way to do it using strictly the WebGrid / CSS.

First, make the WebGrid table render with a client ID so that you can target it:

```
 @grid.GetHtml(
     // code here
     htmlAttributes: new { id = "mygrid" }
 )
```

Now add the styles using JQuery with the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
<script>
    // select the column named "Name" and update its width
    var idx = $("#mygrid th:contains('Name')").attr("width", 100);
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for some reason, I guess is because the <th> tag generated does not actually contain that word... It contains a <div> tag and then inside that one it appear 'Name'

Comment: @DavidVelardeRobles it should still work -- `:contains` doesn't search for an exact match, just a substring.  It is case sensitive though.

Comment: Well, I did present my homework already but thank you for your help :)